# Get only one row from hashmap

Tags: java, android

I'm new for android. 
Now I'm using hashmap to show my listview

Below is my SimpleAdapter,

> ```
> private SimpleAdapter createSimpleAdapter() {
>     List<Map<String, String>> data = this.createData();
>     return new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.menuui,
>             new String[] {
>                     "name", "food"
>             }, new int[] {
>                     R.id.membername, R.id.food
>             });
> }
> ```

I want to get only one row but if I use `listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()` just like this `{food=Onigiri, name=Hashimoto Nanami}`

How can I get only one row ?
If there's not enough information to let you know what I ask, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: To get the name column : `((Map<String, String>)listview.getItemAtPosition(position)).get("name");`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it cannot work

Comment: Oh, i reconstruct the project then it worked, thank you a lot.